# Looping through filtered list and append elements to arrays

Tags: excel, vba

Sheet “FRT” contains filtered data.  For each letter in column A only if column B matches cell value in “B2” I append the corresponding value in column C to a corresponding array.  Column A could contain any combination of letters (A-S) or none of them.  My code only works when all of the letters are present in column A, however, if any of them are missing I get an error message.  Also, my code is very long and redundant.  Please suggest how to improve it.
I included code for "A" to "C" only:

```
Sub test()

    Dim acat As Variant, cell As Range
    Dim bcat As Variant
    Dim ccat As Variant
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FRT")

    LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ReDim fcat(0)
    ReDim bcat(0)
    ReDim ccat(0)

    For Each cell In Worksheets("FRT").Range("A6:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        If cell.Value = "A" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("B2").Cells Then
                   MsgBox (Range("B2").Cells)
                    acat(UBound(acat)) = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    ReDim Preserve acat(UBound(acat) + 1)
        ElseIf cell.Value = "B" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("B2").Cells Then
                    bcat(UBound(bcat)) = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    ReDim Preserve bcat(UBound(bcat) + 1)
        ElseIf cell.Value = "C" And cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("B2").Cells Then
                    ccat(UBound(ccat)) = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    ReDim Preserve ccat(UBound(ccat) + 1)
        End If
            Next cell
            ReDim Preserve acat(UBound(fcat) - 1)
            ReDim Preserve bcat(UBound(bcat) - 1)
            ReDim Preserve ccat(UBound(ccat) - 1)

            Range("D1") = Join(acat, " ")
            Range("E1") = Join(bcat, " ")
            Range("F1") = Join(ccat, " ")



End Sub
```

Here is visual of the data

[image: Filtered Data]

Thank you

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) is there a reason you are iterating through columns B and C when all your If statement worries about is what is in A as conditions for true? 2) When it fails, what line faults?

Comment: I also need to check if the corresponding value in column B matches the value in "B2".  I'm storing the value in column C in an array. I'm trying to avoid the advance filtering step you were helping me with two days ago.  If I get this to work this will give me exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You do that with the offset of the cell value.  You only need to step through column A and use the offset like you are. The For each loop will start in "A6" run through the if statements, it will catch on the first if because it equals "A" then do the things.  The next loop cell will be "B6" and none of the if statements will fire, then it moves to "C6" and again none will fire. There is no need for the extra loops.  With the logic you have it will still work. It will speed it up.

Comment: Clarification: I filter data twice first by column E (I must do this step). However, I can avoid filtering by column B (DRB1*01:01:01) by looping through the list instead and collecting values in arrays.  This way I can avoid using extra sheets.

Comment: I need to change `Worksheets("FRT").Range("A6:A" & LastRow)`?

Comment: That is not the root of your problem but it will speed up sub.  Also you may want to look into `Select Case` instead of `Else If`.  What line is highlighted when you the code stops?

Comment: I get run-time error 9. @ `ReDim Preserve bcat(UBound(bcat) - 1)` I think it's upset that there is no visible B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92613/discussion-between-scott-craner-and-user3781528).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub test()

    Dim cell As Range, lastrow As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim cats(1 To 1, 1 To 19), seps(1 To 19), tmp, i

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FRT")

    lastrow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In Worksheets("FRT").Range("A6:A" & _
                          lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("B2").Value Then
            tmp = cell.Value
            If tmp Like "[A-S]" Then
                i = Asc(tmp) - 64 'Asc("A") is 65...
                cats(1, i) = cats(1, i) & seps(i) & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                seps(i) = " " 'next time we'll add a space for this category
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    Range("D1").Resize(1, 19) = cats

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This version is using arrays and a dictionary object (Tim's is more efficient and easier to maintain)

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Const FIRST_ROW As Byte = 6
    Const A_VALS    As String = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P R S"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, b2 As String, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ltr As Variant, ltrs As Variant, arr As Variant, d As Object, done As Boolean

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FRT")
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Row + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    arr = ws.Range("A" & FIRST_ROW & ":C" & lRow)
    b2 = ws.Range("B2").Value2
    ltrs = Split(A_VALS)

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = 1 To lRow - FIRST_ROW + 1
        If ws.Rows(i + FIRST_ROW - 1).Height > 0 Then
            For Each ltr In ltrs
                If arr(i, 1) = ltr And arr(i, 2) = b2 Then
                    d(ltr) = d(ltr) & " " & arr(i, 3)
                    done = True:    Exit For
                Else
                    If done Or arr(i, 2) <> b2 Then Exit For
                End If
            Next:   done = False
        End If
    Next
    i = 4
    For Each ltr In ltrs
        If Len(d(ltr)) > 0 Then ws.Cells(1, i) = d(ltr)
        i = i + 1
    Next
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 4), ws.Cells(1, i)).Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```